# Jquery multiple selectors and multiple contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I search a div with multiple selectors each with a contains in one jquery string? It needs to be a AND not OR search .

```
$('.row .people:contains("James") .tags:contains("episode")')
```

The above selection should return the first div from below.

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">James</span>
  <span class="tags">episode</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">Bill</span>
  <span class="tags">episode</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">James</span>
  <span class="tags">podcast</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are `.people` and `.tags` siblings and children of `.row` or what? Showing the relevant HTML would help.

Comment: Yes they are. I will add some html

Comment: You forgot to specify if the targeted div of your jQuery selector is `.row` or `.tags`. It's quite important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted an answer that worked, but then deleted it. Using the "~" tilde selector allowed for me to do the selection in one string so I can build the string based off of multiple contains with multiple selectors.

```js
$('.row .people:contains("James") ~ .tags:contains("episode")').parents('.row').addClass('highlighted');
```

```css
.row.highlighted {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">James</span>
  <span class="tags">episode</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">Bill</span>
  <span class="tags">episode</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">James</span>
  <span class="tags">podcast</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) to check if an element contains certain descendants. You can nest `:contains` within your `.has()` statement.

That'll allow you to check if `.row` contains a `span` with certain text.

Then you can add a second `.has()` statement to check that it has *both* spans with the matched text.

Note that in your example HTML, doing the check the way you describe is overcomplicating things because you could just do `.row:first-child`, but assuming you really do need to check things this way, this is the way to go.

Example:

```js
$('.row').has('.people:contains("James")').has('.tags:contains("episode")').addClass('highlighted');
```

```css
.row.highlighted {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">James</span>
  <span class="tags">episode</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">Bill</span>
  <span class="tags">episode</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="people">James</span>
  <span class="tags">podcast</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, although I wanted it in one string. Someone commented early but deleted an answer using ".row .people:contains("James") ~ .tags:contains("episode")" which worked. The tilde worked. This allowed for me to build a string with dynamic contains searches

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure if you literally meant one big long phrase like that or not. The tilde use there is clever. My thinking was that either way you still have one selector that you can then chain functions onto, but maybe my version won't work for your actual use case. Regardless, since the other person deleted their answer, feel free to post it yourself and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery .has() function however in the example code that you have you are missing a comma between the two selectors.

Should be.....

```
$('.row .people:contains("James"), .tags:contains("episode")');
```

Comment: This searches with OR, not with AND.